# Excel Power Query change format of column to custom number format

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a query in Power Query Editor with multuple applied steps. I have a column that is text that i need to change to number in the following format: 000.000

I can do this manually in excel but is there a way to force this format for all values by adding the applied step to my current query?

Tried the Transform Format option but do not have the value available.

Comment: PowerQuery only handles data types and not data "display" formatting. As an example, a date column in PQ is just that, you can't format it (unless you save it as Text).

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to add decimals or replace the thousands separator?

For thousands separator, you can set regional by right clicking the column

[image]

but I believe you also need to have the windows machine also set to the proper regional setting to display properly

If it is just a matter of display, you can add a custom column

```
= Number.ToText([OtherColumnNameHere],"0,00")
```

but that will return a text that looks good but can't be used

Comment: the text field if an export from another source. it consists of numbers but need to be forced into 000.000 number format.

Comment: As answered, you can set the numbers format region to something like Indonesia but unless windows setting is also set to that region, it would display properly. Otherwise, use the text option